# Mass in Lagrangian, squared or not

Tags: mass, field-theory, fermions, dimensional-analysis, higgs

How come sometimes we have $m\phi^2$ in a Lagrangian (e.g. Dirac) but we also have $m^2\phi^2$ instead (e.g. scalar field).

I was reading about Higgs mechanism, for W/Z boson we have $m^2$ equals whatever the coefficient of $W^\dagger W$ and $Z^\dagger Z$ is, but for fermion mass we have $m_f\bar{\psi}\psi$ rather than $m_f^2$.

I'm confused when we will have which case.

Comment: Scalar fields and spinor fields have different dimensions because their kinetic terms involve different numbers of derivatives. Do you understand what the dimension of the action or the Lagrangian density must be?

Comment: @G.Smith That makes sense now considering their dimensions!